# ASP.NET Core MVC Form not input values from foreach loop

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a form to capture the number of tickets a user would like for an item.

[image]

However, only the first `item_id` is being added, if I enter values into item 2 or 3, then nothing inputs to the table.

Below is the my view that I'm using to pass the data to my controller.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
@model IEnumerable<HR.HolidayFamiliesApplication.Web.Models.RaffleList>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RaffleList";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertRecords", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Raffle_ID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Raffle_Item_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Raffle_Item_Description)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Raffle_ID)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_ID" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model => @item.Raffle_ID) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Raffle_Item_Name)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_Item_Name" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model => @item.Raffle_Item_Name) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Raffle_Item_Description)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_Item_Description" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model => @item.Raffle_Item_Description) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Number_of_Tickets">Number_of_Tickets</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Number_of_Tickets" placeholder="Enter # Tickets" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="User_Name" value=@User.Identity.Name />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit" id="InsertRecords" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace foreach loop by for loop

```
@model List<HR.HolidayFamiliesApplication.Web.Models.RaffleList>

....

@for (var i=0;  i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_ID)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_ID" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_ID) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_Item_Name)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_Item_Name" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_Item_Name) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_Item_Description)
                    <input type="hidden" name="Raffle_Item_Description" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Raffle_Item_Description) />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Number_of_Tickets">Number_of_Tickets</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="@model[i].Number_of_Tickets" placeholder="Enter # Tickets" />
                </td>
..... and so on
}
```